# Simulating key strokes, like sendkeys, in node-webkit Windows 7 app

Tags: javascript, dom, node-webkit

Is there a way to "sendkeys" using node-webkit?

I need to actually trigger / emulate the event, meaning including all actions related to that event within a webpage loaded in a node-webkit native Windows 7 app. Specifically, I want to emulate the user pressing the "Enter" key.

I've tried many methods, including KeyboardEvents - an example of my attempt is [see link in comment]. However, the key problem with all the methods I've tried is they merely simulate a key[press/up/down] event.

I understand the security limitations imposed in a normal browser context. However, in my node-webkit deployment, this functionality is critical. I think the functionality may be available through some privileged API. However, I haven't had any luck finding this in the [node-webkit Wiki](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki) or elsewhere online.

Can anyone please direct me toward some way of sending key strokes within a node-webkit application?

EDIT:
Chrome has a method for this that is exposed to extensions [chrome.input.ime.sendKeyEvents](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime#method-sendKeyEvents). It is likely that this is also available through Chromium. It's not clear if this is implemented in webkit, and by extension node-webkit.

EDIT 2:
The node-webkit wiki mentions that [script can emulate user gestures](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Changes-to-DOM#script-can-emulate-user-gestures), however there is almost no informational value contained here. The section reads

> JavaScripts can emulate user gestures while in browsers they can't.

Great, thanks. But how?..

Comment: One of my attempts to solve this, using KeyboardEvents: http://jsfiddle.net/yjc5F/369/.

Comment: That belongs in the question.

Comment: I agree, but StackOverflow has a (new?) rule that questions which contain JSFiddle links must also contain code (assumedly to prevent link rot and poor ux for visitors to the page), however in this case the JSFiddle is not an example of my actual problem or a truly relevant, contextual use case. It's just a demo of what I've tried - as a reference. It adds no value for me to add that code to the question - it actually detracts from my primary goal.

Comment: were you ever able to figure this one out?

Comment: I was not. I will be looking into it again soon.

Comment: I've got men!! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447911/how-execute-a-combination-key-on-node-webkit-like-c-sharp-sendkeys