# Trigger keydown/up/press on whatsapp web interface

Tags: javascript, jquery

The ERP of my company was working just fine till today but not whatsapp did some change in their web interface that broke my JS code. If you open web.whatsapp.com you will see that you can send messages there.

I have an automated script that searches for specific users (that have debt with my company) and send them a message in whatsapp. I usually do this:

```
janela = window.open("https://web.whatsapp.com");
```

After the page loads my system simulates a click in the SEARCH icon using this very simple code:

```
evt_temp = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt_temp.initEvent("mousedown",true,false);
$(janela.window.document).find("[data-icon=\"search\"]").get(0).dispatchEvent(evt_temp);
```

After that I set the value of the input element that appears using this code:

```
$(janela.window.document).find("#input-chatlist-search").val("Contact Name");
```

Before today, when I executed the code above everything worked perfectly. NOW, when I execute the code above everything LOOKS to work fine (see print screen below) BUT for some reason whatsapp is not triggering the search (I already tried firing keydown/up/press events on the input but no luck). See image attached.[image]

Comment: very sad this is not working ;(

Comment: could you make it work eventually?

Comment: @Samul is your workaround still working?

Answer (score 0):

same problem here.

I solved by using NWJS and VBScript.

how I did it:

1) I writed small app (html) for NWJS  with an iframe to https://web.whatsapp.com/

2) Focus on the wsp search text input using javascript

3) Using NWJS api, run the VBScript to paste the name of the contact

More info about VBScript

[How execute a combination key on node-webkit like c# sendkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447911/how-execute-a-combination-key-on-node-webkit-like-c-sharp-sendkeys)

If you need more help or the code just ask.

best regards

Comment: Thanks my friend!!! I didnt understand very well what you did. My approach is this: I open web.whatsapp.com in a new window and from the opener I do all the automation (focus the input, set the value of the search input...). The only way I came to solve this problem was a "hack" but it works very well: a powershell script listens for a specific file size in Chrome CACHE folder. When powershell detects this file it fires the SPACEBAR press in the current active window and after that the powershell script deletes the file and waits till it appear again.

Comment: The way I make my js code to save the cache file is very simple $("<img/>").attr("src","http://www.example.com/cacheablefile.jpg") . I execute this code everytime I need my powershell script to press SPACEBAR! I tested it and is working flawlessly BUT I think your alternative is easier, would you mind telling me how you did the VBScript part?

Answer (score 0):

basically NW JS is Chrome but with NODE-JS functions. That means it let you execute commands on the system, or read/write files on your HD.

1) You have to download NWJS ( https://nwjs.io )

2) Extract the zip file

3) In the folder with nw.exe create a file called "package.json"

4) Add this to that file: (the name of the app, the version and the entry file)

```
{
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.html"
}
```

5) Now you have to write the "index.html" and that html is showned in your APP

6) Create a small VBscript called "paste.vbs" in the same folder as nw.exe. This file only simulate a ctrl+v convination, to paste the content of your clipboard.

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WScript.Sleep 10
shell.SendKeys "^V"
```

7) Run the nw.exe (with this options)

```
C:\nwjs> nw.exe --no-sandbox
```

here is my index.html file

```
<script>
    //NW gui utils
    var gui = require('nw.gui');
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WSP Web</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="t1"/>
    <button onclick="f1()">RUN</button>

    <iframe id="wsp1" src="https://web.whatsapp.com" width=100% height=700px nwdisable nwfaketop></iframe>
  </body>
  <script>
    //Function to validate the OS and what command need to be used
    function getCommandLine() {
        switch (process.platform) { 
            case 'darwin' : return 'open';
            case 'win32' : return 'start';
            case 'win64' : return 'start';
            default : return 'xdg-open';
        }
    }

    //Function that call the VBScrip
    function Paste(){
        var sys = require('util');
        var exec = require('child_process').exec; 

        //Run the VBScript
        exec(getCommandLine() + ' ' + "paste.vbs"); 
    }

    //Main Function
    function f1(){      
        var iframe= document.getElementById("wsp1").contentWindow;

        //Focus the text input
        var evt1 = new CustomEvent('focus', {'view': window,'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true});
        iframe.document.getElementById("input-chatlist-search").dispatchEvent(evt1);        

        //Put the name of your contact in the computer clipboard (to be pasted with ctrl+v)
        var clipboard = gui.Clipboard.get(); 
        clipboard.set("your contact name", 'text');

        //paste the clipboard content using the VBscript
        Paste();
    }

  </script>

</html>
```